# Tracking Android Phone via IMEI number

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lost-phone, gps-tracking

I have lost my Android Phone. How can I track it via IMEI number.

Can I install any application which can given me the number of SIM currently on given IMEI number.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

## [TRACK IMEI (website)](http://www.trackimei.com/)

> TRACK IMEI is here to help you locate your lost mobile. If you have lost your mobile and remember the 14/15 digit IMEI number of your mobile which is a unique number for every mobile then you can register you mobile with us, if any of our dealers across the world will come across that mobile having that IMEI number we will contact you on the details provided by you while registering with us.
>
> If you have already registered with us the details then you can search for your mobile by entering the IMEI number in the below search for IMEI number field.

---

## [Track IMEI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.track.trackimei) <sup>(useful before you lost the device)</sup>

> Have you ever had your phone lost or stolen, and then had it reset or had the battery die? Traditional tracking software will not be able to help you because it requires the phone to be on and your account attached. This is where Track IMEI comes in.
>
> Track IMEI is a mobile phone tracking system that stores your phone’s past and current location in a secure database which you and only you have access to. This means that if a criminal resets your phone, you will be able to track it the entire way until it was reset. Most of the time this is at the persons house, and you are then able to let the police know.
>
> **Current features:**
>   Track past and current location of phone at a time interval set by you
>   Change the time interval from our easy to use online interface located at www.trackimei.ca
>   View your current and past location on a map in the application
>
> **How to Use:**
>   1. Install the app on any supported Android powered smart phone.
>   2. Create an account directly on the phone.
>   3. Once created, log into your newly created account right on your device.
>   4. Go under settings and turn on background update and select the tracking interval you want
>
> That is it! You can now log in at www.trackimie.ca with the same login info to view your device history.

[image: Screenshot 01] [image: Screenshot 02]

Comment: Is giving imei number in these sites safe?

Comment: Does not seem to work!