# Installing Plan B on Samsung Galaxy Ace 3

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 I have no tracking device installed on it and the WiFi and GPS are off. I can call it and know the [imei](/questions/tagged/imei) number. I've tried to install Plan B but it says it is not compatible. Please help.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Tracking Android Phone via IMEI number](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52099/tracking-android-phone-via-imei-number)

Answer (score 0):

Plan B is only available on Android 2.0-2.3.

What you can try is [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager). It's mostly preinstalled and enabled on more recent versions of android.